# Login and hash pages not found

Tags: datasette

I'm having trouble accessing `/-/password-tool` and `/-/login`.

On my Arch Linux machine in a virtual environment running Python 3.8.5, I ran `pip install datasette-auth-passwords`.

I edited `metadata.json` so it includes:

```
"plugins": {
     "datasette-auth-passwords": {
        "someusername_password_hash": {
            "$env": "PASSWORD_HASH_1"
        }
     }
}
```

I used the [password tool](https://datasette-auth-passwords-demo.datasette.io/-/password-tool) to create a hash.

In my terminal, I ran this:

```
PASSWORD_HASH_1='pbkdf2_sha256$...' datasette serve databases/*.db -m metadata.json --template-dir=templates/ --debug
```

(The `...` represents the rest of the hash that I didn't paste here of course.)

When I navigated my browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8001/-/login` I was met with an "Error 404" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had an old version of datasette installed, so I ran `pip install --upgrade datasette`.